# How first statement feels more natural, when both statements are conveying the same information?

Tags: writing-style, phrase-usage, paraphrasing

I am new to English language, while revising I was paraphrasing the 1st statement and got the 2nd. What I don't understand is WHY the 1st statement feels more natural while reading them when both statements are conveying essentially the same information.

Statement 1

> During Aurangzeb's reign, the Mughal Empire began to deteriorate, leading to utter paralysis of the empire's administration and finances during the reigns of successive generations of Mughal emperors.

Statement 2

> The process of decline of the Mughal Empire had set in during Aurangzeb's reign, which during the reign of succeeding generations of Mughal rulers led to total paralysis of administration and finances of the empire.

Comment: The original version tells the reader that a decline started during Aurangzeb's reign. Your version assumes that the reader knows that there was a decline and tells us when it began. The main problem is that your use of _which_ implies that it was Aurangzeb's reign that led to paralysis.

Comment: I concede on the first point that the first part of my sentence assumes that the reader already knows that the decline was there and my statement just tell us where it began, but I believe that ending the first half while emphasising on "deterioration" and following the next half of the sentence with "leading" in the first sentence, is essentially have the same effect as the second one with the use of 'which'.

Comment: I was only trying to explain the difference between the two versions. I don't consider yours 'less natural', just slightly different - _except_ for the "Aurangzeb's reign, which...". At the risk of being accused of 'proof-reading', I would suggest "...and, during the reigns of succeeding... Mughal rulers, it led...".

Comment: Thank you for the help , I will make that edit,  you are right it makes it sound better, is there a reason why 'which' feel awkward in this sentence ? Is there anything specific with regards to usage of which that I am missing here?

Comment: As I said in my original comment, putting _reign_ and _which_ together sounds as though you mean that his reign caused the paralysis.

Comment: The second form more clearly shows that the subject is the *deterioration*, rather than the reign. Consider
> The deterioration of the Mughal Empire that began during Aurangzeb's reign, continued through succeeding generations of Mughal rulers and led in time to the total paralysis of administration and finances of the empire.

Comment: @djs , thanks for the explanation, also shouldn't it be : "and in time, it led to....". Rather than:  "and led in time to....."

Comment: @harshgarg The anaphore you propose wouldn’t be correct, you already have the subject for the verb “led”. If you want to play with the rhythm to allude to the length of time that the deterioration took, you could write “and, in time, led to…”. Spoken out loud, the commas would naturally cause one to breath in around “in time”, and by stretching out the sentence would give depth to the message that much time passed.